# Format the infusionsoft return date using php

Tags: php, timezone

i worked on the code to get subscription start date & end date from the infusionsoft and it return in this format

**Start date=20151217T00:00:00**

**EndDate=20161217T00:00:00**

how i can format to YYYY/MM/DD H:M:S ?

and what the '**T**' stands for

Comment: you can try this <?php
$a = "2015-12-17";
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s' , strtotime($a));
// gives 20151217
$a = "2016-12-17"; 
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s' , strtotime($a)); 
// gives 20161217
?>   will give output 2015-12-17 00:00:002016-12-17 00:00:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **T**, according to the the ISO 8601 standard, is the delimiter between the date and time parts.

See: [ISO 8601 standard, Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

There are two functions you could use:

1. **strtotime(date_time_string)**

   Converts a date/time string into a timestamp.
2. **date(format, timestamp)**

   Formats a timestamp into a string according to "format".

The example code…

```
$so_string = '20151217T00:00:00';
$eo_string = '20161217T00:00:00';

$sd_stamp = strtotime($so_string);
$ed_stamp = strtotime($eo_string);

$f_datetime ='Y/m/d H:i:s';

echo 'Start date<br />';
echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;original: '  . $so_string . '<br />';
echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;timestamp: ' . $sd_stamp . '<br />';
echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;formatted: ' . date($f_datetime,$sd_stamp) . '<br /><br />';
echo 'End date<br />';
echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;original: '  . $eo_string . '<br />';
echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;timestamp: ' . $ed_stamp. '<br />';
echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;formatted: ' . date($f_datetime,$ed_stamp) . '<br />';
```

…will produce this output:

```
Start date
   original: 20151217T00:00:00
   timestamp: 1450306800
   formatted: 2015/12/17 00:00:00

End date
   original: 20161217T00:00:00
   timestamp: 1481929200
   formatted: 2016/12/17 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have the current start and end dates stored in `$startDate` and `$endDate` variables...

```
$formattedStartDate = date("Y/m/d H:i:s", strtotime($startDate));
$formattedEndDate = date("Y/m/d H:i:s", strtotime($endDate));
```

This makes use of the [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) functions

As far as the "T" goes...

> Note that the "T" appears literally in the string, to indicate the
>   beginning of the time element, as specified in ISO 8601.

https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime-970915

Answer (score 0):

You can format the time using date function.

```
date('YYYY/MM/DD H:M:S',strtotime('$date_value'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This uses DateTime with the createFromFormat function.
For more information, click [here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).

Requires PHP 5 >= 5.3.0, PHP 7

```
//infusionsoft format
$startDate = '20151217T00:00:00';
$endDate = '20161217T00:00:00';

//create DateTime object
$startDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd\TH:i:s', $startDate);
$endDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd\TH:i:s', $endDate);

//get DateTime with specified format
$newStartTime = $startDateTime->format('Y/m/d H:i:s');
$newEndTime = $endDateTime->format('Y/m/d H:i:s');
```